# Strange Exoskeleton Found in Maine: What is It?

Tags: zoology, entomology, plant-anatomy

There is a gall like object or exoskeleton attached to a plant stem I have found. At first I thought it was a cicada but it is not. The object cannot be identified by me. Attached are some pictures of it. Could you identify it?

[image: One View]

[image: Bottom view]

[image: Another View]

[image: Top View]

Comment: It's a praying mantis egg case. It won't have "legs" until the eggs hatch. If you're lucky and watchful, you'll see a bunch of tiny praying mantises around it (if you put it back) and the shrubs around it in late spring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to me the ootheca of a mantis before larvae eclosion. You can read more about it [here](https://www.amentsoc.org/insects/glossary/terms/ootheca).

[image]
[image].jpg

Comment: There were no legs or anything.

Comment: https://www.google.es/search?q=mantis+ootheca. If you think that is the exuvia (outer skin) of an insect because it is a thin paperlike membrane with nothing inside, then it is not a mantis ootheca because it would need to have the egg chambers inside to be one. It can not be appreciated from the photo.

Comment: Are they easy to find?

Comment: I used to find about a dozen egg cases a year on my property in PA, Sometimes more. Yet we only had three, maybe four adults active that I could find.